# Touch buttons on UITableView's backgroundView?

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have put some buttons on the bottom of `backgroundview` of a `UITableView`, and set a transparent `tableFooterView` with a height to show the buttons when scroll table to the bottom. The effect is something showing below.

[image]

But the buttons are unable to click. I've tried overiding

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
  [self.backgroundview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

of the tableView class, when click the buttons, error raise.

Google says the touch event handling of tableview is very complex TvT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad design concept.

a) entire UITableView reacts to touches. Making partial areas pass touches to the subview is prone to errors.

b) what will happen if your table only have few cells?

The better approach:

Make the last cell in the table to be your bottom menu. Or the footer view to be the menu.
It will always show up as the last element and it will always react to the touches.